# How can I filter script tag in input field with html5 pattern?

Tags: html

I would like to use pattern attribute for I can filter script tags.
For example for intput pattern:

```
<input type="text" name="HasAPattern" pattern="[0-9A-Z]{3}" title="Enter vaild characters">
```

That's becouse I don't whant run script or php for this.
Actually I trying protect myself for user can run script or XSS and other attack and this looks like a good and simple solution for me.
Of course this not only protection,but the frist step is, exclude every script opportunity in input fild.
Unfortunately, the above pattern does not work well because it classifies all invalid characters.

Comment: *"That's becouse I don't whant run script or php for this."* -- but you really have to if you want to protect against XSS attacks. Any JavaScript/HTML filters can be trivially disabled by anyone who really wants to.

Comment: Unfortunetly, I have some script which need to design.